# parse array and extract string of same length

Tags: java, arrays, list

my first question.

lets say i have arraylist of strings in java

```
ArrayList<string> s= new ArrayList<string>;
```

and it contains sorted list by size.

```
s.add("ab");
s.add("abc");
s.add("aab");
s.add("baab");
s.add("abcd");
```

what i want to do is, iterate the list and pick group of elements which has same length and put into seprate array of arrays.

Group 1 ab
Group 2 abc,aab and so on...

i am doing this in java please help

Comment: For one thing, it's `List<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: what did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since they're sorted by size already it's easy. Here's one way that works:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> listofLists = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
int length = -1;
for(String str : s) { // where s is your sorted ArrayList of Strings
    if(str.length() > length) {
        listofLists.add(new ArrayList<String>());
        length = str.length();
    }
    listofLists.get(listofLists.size()-1).add(str);
}
```

At the end, `listofLists` will be an `ArrayList` of `ArrayLists` containing groups of `Strings` of the same length. Again, this depends on `s` (your `ArrayList<String>`) being sorted by size. Also, `String` must be capitalized there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code "it works as you need"

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> s = new ArrayList<String>();
        s.add("ab");
        s.add("abc");
        s.add("aab");
        s.add("baab");
        s.add("abcd");
        String[] group1 = new String[s.size()];
        String[] group2 = new String[s.size()];
        String[] group3 = new String[s.size()];

        for(int i = 0 ; i < s.size() ; i++){
            if(s.get(i).length() == 2)
                group1[i] = s.get(i);
            else if(s.get(i).length() == 3)
                group2[i] = s.get(i);
            else 
                group3[i] = s.get(i);
        }
        for(String ss : group1){
            if(ss == null)
                break;
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(String ss : group2){
            if(ss == null)
                continue;
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
        System.out.println();
        for(String ss : group3){
            if(ss == null)
                continue;
            System.out.println(ss);
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it useful for you.

Comment: This solution only works for the example input given.

Comment: you can take input from the user also